# How to extract text independently from each row of a text area?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below code. 
I will put a list of values in the text area.
and the iframe should concatenate the value from the a row to the hardcoded URL and when I click next it should concatenate the value from the next row; when I click previous the value from the previous row.

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<button>Previous</button>
<button>Next</button>
<textarea rows="10" cols="20">
Values here
</textarea>
</br>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.domain.com/"*&rowValue from the textarea* height="1200px" width="1200px">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Here's the code after @Adeneo replied:
Here's the code I wrote using your reference but I somehow cant get it to work. Also, if possible can the script also display which ASIN am I currently viewing above the iframe?

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" value="">
ASINs here
</textarea>
<button id="go">Go</button>
<br/>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/" height="100%" width="100%">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<script>var domain='http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/';

$('#prev, #next').on('click', function(e) {
    var Myval = $('textarea').val().split('\n'),
        now = $('#myframe').attr('src').replace(domain, '');
    if (Myval.indexOf(now)==-1) {
        var src=domain+Myval[0];
    }else{
        var p = Myval.indexOf(now)!==0 ? Myval.indexOf(now)-1 : Myval.length-1,
            n = Myval.indexOf(now)==(Myval.length-1) ? 0 : Myval.indexOf(now)+1,
            src = e.target.id=='next' ? domain+Myval[n] : domain+Myval[p];
    }
    $("#myframe").attr('src', src);
    console.log(src);
});
?
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
var domain='http://www.domain.com/'; //could also be gotten from src attr.

$('#prev, #next').on('click', function(e) {
    var Myval = $('textarea').val().split('\n'),
        now = $('#myframe').attr('src').replace(domain, '');
    if (Myval.indexOf(now)==-1) {
        var src=domain+Myval[0];
    }else{
        var p = Myval.indexOf(now)!==0 ? Myval.indexOf(now)-1 : Myval.length-1,
            n = Myval.indexOf(now)==(Myval.length-1) ? 0 : Myval.indexOf(now)+1,
            src = e.target.id=='next' ? domain+Myval[n] : domain+Myval[p];
    }
    $("#myframe").attr('src', src);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hxxVD/1/)

And don't put your HTML in the head section of the document, read up on doctypes, head, body etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm stuck again. I have never used scripts or programmed in HTML/Javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm stuck again. I have never used scripts or programmed in HTML/Javascript. Below is the code that I modified. I put the buttons and text area in the head so that my iframe takes advantage of the whole area in the body. I sell products on amazon. and ASINs are Amazon Identifiers for products. So If I want to check out my product pages I have to go to each one separately. If I can put everything together in the text box and hit go it should take me to the first page. My product pages need to be in this format www.amazon.co.uk/dp/ASIN
Here is a sample ASIN B004Z2QORW

Comment: I have put the edited code in the question. It will be really helpful if you can get this to work. It'll save a lot of my effort and time.